# Website icon (rel=icon) not appearing in chrome for android

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I have this code on every page of my website.

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="http://compesh.com/assets/graphics/touch-icon-chrome.png" />
```

Yet when I go to my website on Chrome for Android and tap "Add to home screen" my icon never shows up in the dialog. My image is of the correct size and exists.

What is going on?

[I have used this documentation from Google.](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/browser-customization/)

**Update**

My website is http://compesh.com
Look at the page source and see if I've made any mistakes.

It works in Firefox for Android but not Chrome for Android and Chrome for Windows. I see this in Firefox WebIDE

[image: broken website image in firefox webide]

**2nd Update**
Firefox for Windows is not showing my favicon image in the tab. Instead it is showing the wrong image and scaling it down to 16x16 pixels, instead of using my 16x16 favicon I specified in my web page.

Comment: Have you tried changing the source to just the file name? This assumes your asset is in the same directory as your root.

Comment: I cannot change the `href` attribute to just say the file name, as then I would need multiple copies of the image in different folders.

Comment: Have you cleared cache? Do you have other link tags for iOS icons that you have confirmed work with their respective devices?

Comment: I have cleared the cache and have removed all the icon link tags except for the google chrome one, and it still doesn't work. I haven't tested the icon out on an iPhone.

Comment: try by fixing these errors https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fcompesh.com%2F

Comment: regarding your second update, do you have a favicon in the root directory? If so this is what Firefox is picking up

Comment: @desbest I'd also note this site is great for checking what you have and what you are missing

https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?protocol=http&site=compesh.com#.WhMLLBO0Msk

Comment: @desbest It's also recommend that all favicon images are located in the root directory.

Eg.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: @desbest your issue is resolved, see my answer. i have tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed below div (maybe mistakenly)

```
<div style="display: none;">
```

tag right after

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=610">
```

in your head tag, that's why browser is closing your head tag before that div and favicon not showing. Remove that div from your head and everything will be fine.

Comment: The div is supposed to be there.

Comment: You're right, the `<div style="display: none;">` is causing the issue. I have changed my code to move things around to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: The reason why I had that `<div>` there in the first place was because I was including javascript in the `<script>` tag that was called inline instead of a URL. For practical, technical and speed reasons it had to be inline. I used the `<div>` to make the `<script>` tag invisible as it was causing glitches in my website design as it was adding extra spaces or padding. The javascript would still run if the tag was invisible. To get the favicons to work I had to spend hours updating my code to solve both problems at the same time.

Answer (score 19):

hey try this one just go to https://www.favicon-generator.org 
and choose your file and click on create favicon.

Now Download the rar file and extract where your project file is and then copy below code

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

now refresh the browser or try in another browser

Answer (score 2):

buddy you are using **html 4**, why don't you use **html 5.**

and in href="/" it's not necessary to give full path/link. in your code
just do some minor change. i hope it will help you.
i guess @sarvesh has explain you everything

```
<link rel="icon" type="image" href="assets/graphics/favicon.png" sizes="16x16">
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a png file as your high res icon, can you try adding the type attribute, like so:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://compesh.com/assets/graphics/touch-icon-chrome.png" sizes="192x192" />
```

This helps distinguish it as a png file and not a regular favicon.ico file.

Comment: I've cleared the cache and tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your href :

```
http://compesh.com/assets/graphics/touch-icon-chrome.png?v=2
```

You see the "?v=2" for clearing cache directly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<link href="https://compesh.com/assets/favigen/favicon-96x96.png" rel="icon" sizes="96x96" />
```

Works fine on my android phone.
I tested it on
http://helledussen.com/test

Comment: Thank you for your help. You led me to solve the problem. You can delete the test page now.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this as well, and a solution I found was to make 4 different sizes and link to them with rel="apple-touch-icon". It  has been tested on iPhone, iPad, Android, and Blackberry:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="../images/YourIconName57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../images/YourIconName.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="../images/YourIconName.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="../images/YourIconName.png" />
```

Comment: Are you making sure that your images are exactly square? 
If you upload a high res image of your icon to this site, it will generate a zip containing all of the images and give you the HTML required to include in your header. https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Comment: I've used favicon generator with square icons and all the links are not broken, and it still doesn't display a website icon on google chrome for android.